Large number of polygons with react-three-fiber
I need to display thousands of polygons (2d) of different shapes with react-three-fiber.
I thought the best option would be to use instances of the same polygon with, let's say 100 vertices. And then to move the vertices of each instances in its vertex shader according to its shape.
I'm able to show triangles with react-three-drei Instances, but I cannot change the position of the vertices of each of those triangles.


While the approach you're describing (use instancing, and in the vertex shader use the instance ID or other data to procedurally rearrange vertices) is possible, it could be fairly complex depending on the topologies of the shapes.
I think that THREE.BatchedMesh is probably a better option here. It allows you to draw any number of distinct geometries with different vertices in a single draw call, as long as they share a single material. For an example using BatchedMesh in R3F, see:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/batchedmesh-3pf9d2
The example uses a custom material, but if you only need per-instance color (and not per-instance values of other PBR properties) then the built-in MeshStandardMaterial would be fine.

Yes it might work. I will try BatchedMesh but how is it that I cannot move an individual vertex in my instances?

You certainly can move an individual vertex in your instances, it's just a much more complicated way to draw differing shapes. You'd need to write a custom vertex shader generating each of the possible shapes, perhaps with a lookup texture storing vertex positions of each vertex for each possible shape. Note that textures have strict size limits in WebGL.

My idea was actually to store vertex positions of each vertex for each possible shape in the instancedBufferAttribute. That would allow me to morph the shapes as will with the vertex shader, if I understand correctly. But in my codesandbox, I'm unable to control the vertices individually. The offset is always applied to all of them.

Instance attributes can contain only one value (e.g. one vec4) per instance — not one value per vertex. It won't be possible to control individual vertices of individual instances in that way.
